# Is it correct to say “take one mile at a time”?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to say:

> Take one mile at a time.

Or is it better to say:

> Take **it** one mile at a time.

Comment: Correct in what context? Can you give an example sentence?

Comment: Both samples exhibit correct grammar.

Comment: @KateBunting for example, when I want to tell someone “you don’t have to do everything at once, take only one mile at time”

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you!

Comment: I have answered your question, but in future I suggest you consider whether posting to our sister site, SE English Language Learners, would be more appropriate.

Comment: @David Then why answer the question?

Comment: @Joachim — I had my reasons, but I think it better not to rehearse them here.

Comment: @David Please, indulge me :) The point is that I see this frequently here, and keep thinking of raising the issue on Meta, but would like to know the reasons behind it first.

Comment: @Joachim — I look at a question, can answer it, but think the question elementary and that the OP's English suggests a  non-native speaker. Normally I would vote to close or suggest migration to ELL. However then I see that someone has given an answer as a comment and the OP has regarded this as an answer. Nobody has yet voted to close, and I feel strongly that this violates the SE model (not to be discussed here — I have a post on Meta). I think it best to provide the answer as an answer. To guide the OP in the future, I flag ELL in a comment. I may have been wrong, but those were my reasons.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The English phrase is:

> Take one **step** at a time.

See, e.g. [The Cambridge Dictionary on-line](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-step-at-a-time)